# Database design question - Performance needed

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I created an inventory system which mostly is using a server-sided scripting language to do all the work. To try and get some performance gains I am looking to better design my database to try and minimizing the scripts.

I have a table named metal_part which has a one to one relationship with five other tables, basically the other tables are other parts, which those parts then have a one to one relationship with a few other tables.

When I query metal_part I need all the UPC numbers from each table, so its direct one to one relationships need to get their own information from their direct one to one relationship tables ect... Is it possible to make a huge query to build it all and put it in a form at like:

```
(###) - ####/##/##/## [a-z]
```

Using a query? or do I have to get all the information and concat it using a scripting language?

Thanks

Comment: Anything is possible when you're in Pappy's Cabin. But seriously, I'm not sure what you're asking. I think you are just asking about a JOIN condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get all of the information you need using a standard join, and then, with the concat function appropriate to your database (see here http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html) you can form the string you want.

Comment: What I really am trying to ask is whether concat is a good practice with queries? Or leave the manipulation to the scripting language?

Comment: That strongly depends on the performance specifics of your application. In some cases, doing this work on the database side of things will save you time, in others, doing it on your web server will serve you time, and in others still, doing it on the client side is most advantageous

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.

I'm guessing you are talking about matching on a primary key called partnumber or something like that.

You can do this using a query like

```
SELECT mp.partnumber
  , mp.UPC_number
  , wp.UPC_number
  , pp.UPC_number
FROM metal_parts mp
INNER JOIN wood_parts wp ON (wp.partnumber = mp.partnumber)
INNER JOIN plastic_parts pp ON (pp.partnumber = mp.partnumber)
WHERE mp.partnumber = '8874578127';
```

You can also do

```
SELECT mp.partnumber
  , group_concat(mp.UPC_number) as metal_UPCs
  , group_concat(wp.UPC_number) as wood_UPCs
  , group(concat(pp.UPC_number) as plastic_UPCs
FROM metal_parts mp
INNER JOIN wood_parts wp ON (wp.partnumber = mp.partnumber)
INNER JOIN plastic_parts pp ON (pp.partnumber = mp.partnumber)
WHERE mp.partnumber = '8874578127'
GROUP BY mp.partnumber;
```

or

```
SELECT mp.partnumber
  , concat_ws(','
    , group_concat(mp.UPC_number)
    , group_concat(wp.UPC_number)
    , group(concat(pp.UPC_number)
  ) as UPCs_of_parts
FROM metal_parts mp
INNER JOIN wood_parts wp ON (wp.partnumber = mp.partnumber)
INNER JOIN plastic_parts pp ON (pp.partnumber = mp.partnumber)
WHERE mp.partnumber = '8874578127'
GROUP BY mp.partnumber;
```